# CoInitializeEx fails when calling OpenCV method cvLoadImage()

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, opencv, directshow

I am trying to integrate some OpenCV functionality into my application. Currently I have code set up with DirectShow to get a video feed from my camera, which is then showed in an MFC window.  This code cannot be changed or removed.

The code runs completely fine, but regardless of the location i place the following line of code:

```
IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("C:/well.jpg");
```

The webcam fails to initialize correctly and breaks the program.

more directly, i get a FAILED HRESULT at:

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED)
```

More specifically, at some point in my code i Call CDialog::doModal(), which then hits CoInitializeEx(), and thus makes the program fail.

would anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: fails how? whats the error code?

Comment: I added an update that i just found, the code fails when i call CDialog::DoModal, regardless of where cvLoadImage is located at

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CoInitialize will fail if the thread was previously initialized as a different apartment, i.e., if there was a previous CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)

I would guess that OpenCV calls CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED), causing your subsequent calls to CoInitializeEx to fail.  You can confirm this by checking the return of CoInitializeEx - it'll be RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE in this case.

There is no straightforward fix, the most straightforward will be to move the OpenCV calls into a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Michael said check also for external dependent DLL's, if one is missing CoInitialize will also fail.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my MFC app the call to `AfxOleInit` failed with `RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE`.

I cannot ignore the failure (I need the COM inside the app) and I cannot move the OpenCV call to a different thread (as Michael rightly suggests).

I found the thread ["wxwidgets and opencv 1.1 ole initialization error"](http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/58089) that solves my problem: I do not need the video input support from OpenCV and so I can remove the `#define HAVE_VIDEOINPUT 1` as suggested in http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/60060

> go to `_highgui.h`, comment line 96 ("`#define HAVE_VIDEOINPUT 1`")
>   and recompile

It works with OpenCV_1.1pre1a.